# Replace rules change dimension

Tags: replacement, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

This is absolutely driving me crazy, I don't know if this is a bug or what, but replace rule sometimes change dimension of my data.

Say I have data:

```
FLIST={{1,1,1}, {2,2,2}};
```

and replace rule:

```
ReplaceShit = {
A->FLIST[[2]],
B->FLIST[[1]]
};
```

It seems to work fine:

```
(A - B) /. ReplaceShit
{1, 1, 1}
```

However, when I use it in this way it gives different answer:

```
(FLIST[[2]] - B) /. ReplaceShit
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

I have absolutely no idea why this became 3x3 matrix instead 1x3 vector. Please help.

Comment: Look at what happens when you evaluate, say `{2,2,2} - B` on its own.

Comment: Use [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) to see why. `(FLIST[[2]] - B)` is first evaluated to `({2, 2, 2} - B)`, i.e., `({2 - B, 2 - B, 2 - B}` prior to the replacement. The subsequent replacement produces a 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 2):

So, what's happening? First, let's establish that `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) does not have any `Hold*` attributes (not `HoldAll` and not `HoldFirst`.)

```
Attributes[ReplaceAll]
```

> `{Protected}`

Then let's write the expression in its `FullForm`:

```
list = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};
replaceIt = {
   A -> {1, 1, 1},
   B -> {2, 2, 2}
   };

ReplaceAll[list[[1]] - B, replaceIt]
```

Now, since `ReplaceAll` does not have any `Hold*` attribute, arguments will be evaluated *before* being passed to the function. Let's evaluate the arguments. Take them one by one and evaluate them in separate cells.

The first argument evaluates like this:

```
list[[1]] - B
```

> `{1 - B, 1 - B, 1 - B}`

The second argument evaluates in an obvious way. In conclusion, we now have the following expression:

```
ReplaceAll[
 {1 - B, 1 - B, 1 - B}, {
  A -> {1, 1, 1},
  B -> {2, 2, 2}
  }]
```

This is what gets evaluated, and you can probably see from this why you are getting the result that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I get the desired result by using `Unevaluated` function as:

```
Unevaluated[(FLIST[[2]] - B)] /. ReplaceShit
```